# Javascript. simple code but not loading in wer browser. I am just starting

Tags: javascript

Can anyone help me what's wrong with this and why its not loading in web broser, much appreciated, see below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"html://www.w3.org/TR/xhtmll/DTD/xhtmll-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body>

<script type="text javascript">

var myArray = new Array();
myArray[0] = "Bob";
myArray[1] = "Pete";
myArray[2] = "Paul";

document.write("myArray"[0] = " + myArray[0] + "<BR>");
document.write("myArray"[2] = " + myArray[2] + "<BR>");
document.write("myArray"[1] = " + myArray[1] + "<BR>");

myArray[1] = "Mike";
document.write("myArray[1] changed to " + myArray[1]);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: javascript is not java

Comment: `<script>` likely should go in `<head>`. Use a [debugger](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) to find syntax errors. Such questions are off topic here.

Answer (score 0):

Unnecessary quotes:

```
document.write("myArray[0] = " + myArray[0] + "<BR>");
document.write("myArray[2] = " + myArray[2] + "<BR>");
document.write("myArray[1] = " + myArray[1] + "<BR>");
```

Comment: If the answer is "minor syntax error" then it is off topic on this site. Answering only encourages more such questions.

Answer (score 0):

you had made two modifications

1) declaration of javascript tag as `<script type="text/javascript">`

2) remove unecessary quotes `document.write("myArray[0] = " + myArray[0] + "<BR>");`

As already mentioned, its appreciated to ask questions wisely.